# Google Map Showing blank page in my android app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to implement google my app in pizza app but it is showing blank page what should I do?

below my java code.

```
public class FindUsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_us);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(56.855776, 14.829839);

    Marker DSlocation = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Maestro restaurang &
pizzeria").snippet("Click Navigation icon below for navigation"));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,18));
} }
```

my xml file

```
 <fragment
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.example.yodgor777.maestro.FindUsActivity" />
```

my manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yodgor777.maestro">
```

The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Information" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".FindUsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_find_us"></activity>
    </application>

 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this permission in manifest.xml**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Change Your google map Apikey then try it and Check once you `google map api` key is `enable` or not.

Comment: I have implement new api key and added your code to manifest it is still showing blank .
    -->
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
        AIzaSyBnJFSGMRpgyBogcfwAHM8JSfuJ4c1FNaM
    </string>
</resources>

Answer (score 0):

> Enabling the Maps API

Next, Add package name and fingerprint. This provides two fields, one for adding a package name and another for adding the SHA1 from your application signing key.

> You can generate the SHA1 with the following command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore
```

After you have created your SHA1 key and entered it into the text field, click on the blue Create button. You are then presented with a dialog containing the API key that you need to add to your Android app to access the Maps API.

Reference by:
[google developer console](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/registering_an_application):